# Gibbs point process

Tags: point-processes

I am reading in the book Spatial Point Patterns by Baddley et al. that "all finite point process models (under reasonable conditions) can be represented mathematically as Gibbs models". I couldn't find any reference for this statement. Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks!